# Angular Animation gone after sortablejs

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have Angular Component with a collapse animation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'module-result',
  templateUrl: './module-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./module-result.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('collapsedState', [
      state('1', style({height: 0})),
      state('0', style({height: AUTO_STYLE})),
      transition('0 <=> 1', animate('300ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ModuleResultComponent {

  public collapse = true;

  toggleCollapse() {

    this.collapse = !this.collapse;
    console.log('NEW collapse', this.collapse);

  }

}

<div>
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-header" (click)="toggleCollapse()"></div>

    <div class="card-block">

      ...

      <div #reportContainer class="report-container">

        <div class="collapse-content" [@collapsedState]="collapse">
          ...
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The animation is working and collapses/expands the div content.

Now the whole Component is sortable via sortablejs. This part is working too.

But for some reason the first click after drag sort on my card header to trigger the animation changes the boolean `collapse` but does not animate. After another click the view jumps to its state and the animation process is fine.

Only the first trigger does not work after drag sort change.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could post as a working ( or rather failing ) example.That is what the StackSnippets here are for. Or an external Plnkr  if that suits better. This seems more about the parts "not included" in the question more that what you included already.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have created a plunker ... for some reason its working in that minimal example https://plnkr.co/edit/s2uyl8ujawWPHNFNU0LM

Comment: It's actually the reason we ask here for a ["minimal example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because "from experience" most of us are aware that the process of doing so usually highlights the problem. As per which you "should" have something to compare to your code that does not work, and therefore surmise that the "problem" lies in the "differences".

Comment: I have included the code from my plunker in my application but I do not get it to work ... same problem. Are there any differences in using anglunar-cli (I think webpack) and SystemJs?